# Bag File Produced via launch file has 0 duration

Tags: ros, roslaunch, python, rosbag, rospy

I am writing bag file via rosbag. I have implemented a bagwriter class with singleton pattern for writing in bagfile

```
class BagWriter:
_instance = None


def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
    if cls._instance is None:
        cls._instance = super().__new__(cls)
    return cls._instance

def __init__(self, path=None):
    if not path and not self._bag:
        raise ValueError("Path must be provided when creating the first instance of BagWriter")
    
    if path:
        self._bag = self.open_bag(path=path, compression=rosbag.Compression.BZ2)

@validate_path
def open_bag(self, path, compression=rosbag.Compression.NONE):
    return rosbag.Bag(path, 'w', compression)

def write_bag(self, topic, message, time):
    try:
        # rospy.loginfo(time)
        self._bag.write(topic, message, time)
    except Exception as e:
        rospy.logerr(e)

def close_bag(self):
    self._bag.close()
```

and I am initializing this class as

```
bag_writer = BagWriter(config['output_file_name'])
rospy.on_shutdown(bag_writer.close_bag)
```

Now the messages I am writing in bag file are in un-sorted timestamps and often I write the last message with a timestamp equal to first timestamp. but it should be fine.
Now when I run this file directly as script the bag file get created with correct duration

```
$ rosbag info direct_output.bag 
path:         direct_output.bag
version:      2.0
duration:     2:18s (138s)
start:        Sep 20 2023 17:03:34.81 (1695211414.81)
end:          Sep 20 2023 17:05:53.77 (1695211553.77)
size:         37.4 MB
messages:     34743
compression:  bz2 [211/211 chunks; 23.08%]
uncompressed: 159.4 MB @   1.1 MB/s
compressed:    36.8 MB @ 271.1 KB/s (23.08%)
```

but when I run this code via launch file the output bag file has duration 0

```
$ rosbag info ros_output.log.bag 
path:         ros_output.log.bag
version:      2.0
duration:     0.0s
start:        Sep 20 2023 17:03:34.81 (1695211414.81)
end:          Sep 20 2023 17:03:34.81 (1695211414.81)
size:         37.3 MB
messages:     34743
compression:  bz2 [211/211 chunks; 23.05%]
uncompressed: 159.4 MB
compressed:    36.7 MB
```

and here is the launch file

```
<launch>

    <arg name="parameter_file" default="$(find bag_writer)/config/param.yaml" />

    <rosparam command="load" file="$(arg parameter_file)" />

    <node pkg="bag_writer" type="bag_writer.py" name="bag_writer_node" output="screen" required="true">
    </node>

</launch>
```

Now when I compared both of the files the have

- exact same number of messages each with exact same data in them but somehow rosbag command recognizes the duration of later produced file as 0.
- in comparison of file sizes there is a minor difference in file sizes of 0.1 MB which I can't figure out why?

there is also another point that If I try to uncompress later produced file then its duration gets corrected

Please note that I cannot place data inside log file in time order, why running node with roslaunch is causing the issue

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics*, Muhammad Hamza Sajjad Abbasi. I'm seeing `write_bag` defined in your code, but I'm not seeing where it's referenced. How are you getting this to work when you call it directly? I would expect you would either invoke `rosbag record` direct from the launch file, like shown [here](https://answers.ros.org/question/52773/record-with-rosbag-from-launch-file/), or create a class that subscribes to topics and writes them to a rosbag as a part of a callback. Could you please *edit your question* to provide more information about your use case and how you would like this to work?